# group a list of paths based on directory name and file name

Tags: python

I want to sort my paths, based on directory name and then on file name. They are separated by first different folder ("*TENT1*" and "*TENT2*").  Notice that some files are inside "*Job1*" and "*Job2*" folders but some are not but need them sorted as well. Thank you!

```
paths = [
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/Job1/metr-ok_2022_11_28',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/Job1/metr-ok_2022_11_29',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/Job1/weig-ok_2022_11_28',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/Job1/weig-ok_2022_11_29',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/down-ok_2022_11_27',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/down-ok_2022_11_28',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/serv-ok_2022_11_28',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/serv-ok_2022_11_29',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/Job2/metr-ok_2022_11_28',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/Job2/metr-ok_2022_11_29',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/Job2/weig-ok_2022_11_28',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/Job2/weig-ok_2022_11_29',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/down-ok_2022_11_27',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/down-ok_2022_11_28',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/serv-ok_2022_11_28',
    '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/serv-ok_2022_11_29',
]
```

but this is what I want:

```
paths = [
    [
        [
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/Job1/metr-ok_2022_11_28',
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/Job1/metr-ok_2022_11_29'
        ],

        [
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/Job1/weig-ok_2022_11_28',
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/Job1/weig-ok_2022_11_29'
        ],

        [
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/down-ok_2022_11_27',
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/down-ok_2022_11_28',
        ],

        [
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/serv-ok_2022_11_28',
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT1/serv-ok_2022_11_29'
        ],

    ],
    [
        [
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/Job2/metr-ok_2022_11_28',
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/Job2/metr-ok_2022_11_29'
        ],
        [
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/Job2/weig-ok_2022_11_28',
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/Job2/weig-ok_2022_11_29'
        ],
        [
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/down-ok_2022_11_27',
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/down-ok_2022_11_28',
        ],
        [
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/serv-ok_2022_11_28',
            '/var/lib/conc/states/TENT2/serv-ok_2022_11_29',
        ],
    ]
]
```

this is my code:

```
from itertools import groupby
from os.path import dirname
sorted_by_file = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(paths, dirname)]
```

I am struggling how to sort those files once they are sorted by folder name.

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I was using `sorted_by_file = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(paths, dirname)] `but it gives me sorted only by directory name. But I am struggling how to sort based file name after I sorted folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `dirname` function for grouping you have to create your own function which can look like

```
import os.path

def grouper(path):
    d, f = os.path.split(path)
    f = f.split('-')[0]
    return d, f
```

It returns a tuple with the directory and the relevant part of the filename.

It can be used in the same way as you did already in your code:

```
from itertools import groupby
sorted_by_file = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(paths, grouper)]
```